# Hiding parts of the code from other contributors

Tags: java, android, jar

Manager of my team has requested me to hide parts of the codebase of an Android application project from an incoming intern (these parts are mostly related to networking).

How should I approach that - should I create a JAR library and import it to my project (and work on that JAR separately)?

Comment: Adding to @Korcholis answer, can you tell us why you want to hide them? It would help us advise you. What is the exact risk here?

Comment: Looks like nobody else wills to answer...

Answer (score 1):

#### Code copy

If the real matter is the intern to copy your code, then this might be enough (unless he wishes it so much he'd want to reverse engineer the code. Decompress the jar, reverse the `.class` files and here we go).

#### Code use

If the problem is he could use the code in his own projects/other companies, you can't. You may need to make him sign a contract of non disclosure, if it's that important for your team, talk to a lawyer about this.

#### Secrets use

In case it's only related to secret keys, passwords, IPs or so, it could be as easy as extracting these codes in a different file, and everybody having his own copy (you'd have the "good one", and he'd have a test version). This solution implies he'd be using test codes, which should work as long as his internship lasts.

PS: This post is open for additions